# ClassFormatError in Event log android studio

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

My computer crashed randomly and I was editing something in my project. I don't remember my last changes but on restarting android studio, layout isn't visible and the event log displays this error:

```
4.51.37 PM Platform and Plugin Updates: The following components are ready to update: Google Repository, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
4.51.39 PM Gradle sync started
4.52.27 PM Gradle sync completed
4.52.30 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
4.52.33 PM ClassFormatError: minor.project.kickfeed.R$array
4.52.39 PM Gradle build finished in 11s 239ms
4.52.40 PM ClassFormatError: minor/project/kickfeed/R$array
```

How to fix this?

UPDATE:
I had an update to Google Repository and it fixed the error.

Comment: it would be really hard to point to some solution from this log... just try to reinstall android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that something got currupted on your project it happend to me, you can try few things to fix this.

`Go to Build -> Rebuild Project`

If this doen't work try

`Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`